# Geometry nodes UVMap Point distribute mask

Tags: node-editor, geometry, geometry-nodes

Having some trouble with Point instances not appearing where expected using a UVMap as a mask.
Using a simple Black,White image and UVMap to denote each Faces edge, so Points should only appear on edges I'd expect?!

If I move the UV about, the Points will either be there or not, like it's only sampling the first pixel for the entire face. Inverting the image has the opposite effect.

Haven't touched Blender since 2.81 so this is all new to me again.

Then I want to rotate each point 90 degrees randomly (using Local space) It rotates globally it seems.

[image]

Comment: Hello, this method won't work : You need more geometry for the algorithm to know how to interpolate between vertices. The uvs are stored in the vertices, more exactly in loops containg one vertex and 2 edges. It doesn't know what's going on in the texture after that. So it's basically interpolating between a value of 1 and 1 because that's what it sees in the texture edges. Using the Spreadsheet editor might help you understand that better

Comment: It's something about "Face Corner" I see in the parameters which makes sense. I guess I need to rethink and either spit the mesh or find a way to apply to one face. I was maybe going for too lazy an approach. This should be a final effects procedure tbh